# cannot use Qt Xlsx

Tags: c++, linux, qt, xlsx

I have Qt 5.15 Beta-2 in `/opt`. I've also downloaded from [here](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter/archive/master.zip) and built the Qt5::Xlsx module [`qmake`, `sudo make`, `sudo make install`]. Now in `/opt/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/include` there's a directory `QtXlsx` but it contains only one file `QtXlsxDepends`. No `xlsxdocument.h`, `xlsxcell.h` or anything like that, so Qt Creator says `file not found` if I try to include them as in [here](http://qtxlsx.debao.me/qtxlsx-demo-main-cpp.html).

[the output of the build commands](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cvMPx_Xn4ZYZkb2U83AybhztChjruq9g/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, you should see what those commands actually do. IOW, look at their console output. If they don't print anything interesting, try to search how to enable more output. As a side note, you shouldn't run `sudo make`, just `make`, in general. Only `sudo make install` needs it.

Comment: I added a link to the console output. I can see those header files mentioned. You can see that just `make` gave me `mkdir /opt/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/features//include: Permission denied at /opt/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/bin/syncqt.pl line 404.`, that's why `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sought-for headers are in `/opt/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/include/QtXlsx`. So I added `target_include_directories(target PRIVATE /opt/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/include/QtXlsx)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` and the problem went away.